# Why is my code not copying and pasting data?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy certain values from one sheet and paste them into another sheet, however, the following code was working and now it does not. All it does is open the sheet without going back and pasting any data. Can anyone identify what the issue is?

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim arr, i As Long, f As Range, cPaste As Range, col As Long
    
    Dim wbPaste As Workbook, wsPaste As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet, wSrc As Workbook
    
    

    arr = Array("DSCR Analysis", "Commercial Income", "Rental Income", "Other Income", _
            "Total All Income", "Rental Vacancy (%)", "Rental Vacancy ($)", _
            "Commercial Vacancy (%)", "Concessions/Bad Debt (%)", "Concessions/Bad Debt ($)", _
            "Effective Gross Income", "Total Expenses", "NOI", "Facility A Contractual Rate", _
            "MBI Debt Service", "Excess Cash Flow", "DSCR")
               Set wSrc = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MBI DSCR")
    Set wbPaste = Workbooks.Open("BOOK")
    Set wsPaste = wbPaste.Sheets(1) 'for example
 
     col = wsSrc.Columns.Find(What:="MBI", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
    LastRow = wsPaste.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=wsPaste.Range("A1"), _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set cPaste = wsPaste.Cells(LastRow + 1, "C")
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        
  
        Set f = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:=arr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
      
        
        
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            f.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 6).Copy 'copy 6 columns next to the found cell
            cPaste.Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                             Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        End If
        
        Set cPaste = cPaste.Offset(0, 1) 'next paste destination
    Next i

    wsPaste.Range("A1").Value = "Date Added"
    wsPaste.Range("B1").Value = "Name"

    
    
    Rows.AutoFit
    Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

I suspect its from the active workbook being changed but I do not see how the variables are changed like that?

Comment: Maybe `If Not f Is Nothing Then` is `False`?

Comment: I think that is because the active workbook is changing as I am pasting. DO you know how I could change this?

Comment: Then use `ThisWorkbook` instead?

Comment: I am getting an "Error Subscript out of range"? I am unsure why because the name I am using is valid for a sheet in this workbook

Comment: One problem with building VBA code around the "Find" function is that it doesn't reset between uses and it defaults to the values in the user form, so perhaps one of the parameters that you aren't providing in the function has been changed - that would explain intermittent failures.  Add a breakpoint after each the find lines and then look at the values that are calculated and see if they match what you expect.

Comment: ok how would this be done? I think that its not even reaching the if then statement